# Is there a way to easily switch operating systems on a duel install?

Tags: dual-boot

Currently using Ubuntu and Windows 7 duel install. I am wondering if there is an easy way to switch operating systems without having to keep shutting down my computer and turning it back on.

Comment: No, you have to dual boot. Your only other option is virtualization such as KVM or virtualbox

Comment: The name describes what you have: a dual -boot-.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you run one in a virtual machine, no. An OS needs exclusive rights to the entire cpu and root device, and if you tried to boot them simultaneously then they would completely crash the moment one of them issued an instruction after the other had, as the cpu is only meant to handle one kernel thread. Even with the fastest cpu, there is no way to run two OSs at the same time without virtualizing one of them

Comment: Is it possible using the software we have in 2021? having ubuntu and windows boot at the same time and observe no crashes.

Comment: The wording in the original answer when I posted it is a little strange but the assertion still holds. Computers just aren't meant to have two OSs running "directly on the hardware". What would handle scheduling kernel threads if there is no OS (and scheduler) to be the final arbiter?

What has changed somewhat over time is that virtualization has gotten *really good*, and because of both hardware acceleration and some very smart software development you can get basically the same performance from a VM as you do an OS running "directly" on the hardware

Comment: Scheduling kernel threads makes sense. Thanks for the answer!